# Getting NULL pointer exception after making a session factory

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I am getting null pointer exception at the line

```
SessionFactory sesionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory() ;
```

any suggestion what might be causing it ??

error log says this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1797)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1755)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
    at com.hussi.model.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

my Main class File :

```
package com.hussi.model;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("hussi");
        user.setPassword("maria");

        SessionFactory sesionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory() ;
        Session session = sesionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

my model file

```
package com.hussi.model;

public class User 
{
    int user_id;
    String username;
    String password;

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "username==>"+this.username+" : password==>"+this.password;
    }

}
```

my user.hbm.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hussi.model.User" table="users">
         <id name="user_id" type="int" column="user_id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>

        <property name="username">
            <column name="username"/>
        </property>

        <property name="password">
            <column name="password"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my hibernate configuration file : hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/my_hibernate_1</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connecttion.password">root</property>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- MySql Dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Try passing the .xml file as a parameter to the config() as mentioned here http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-directory/

Comment: From the logs it is evident that the session factory is not yet created, one issue is that the hibernate is unable to get the connection of the mysql running, check if the mysql is running.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is typo mistake but your password property named as connecttion.password. Doubled t. Can you correct this and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml` & `user.hbm.xml` should be on the root location on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the prefix **hibernate.** at the hibernate specific property values. For example use **hibernate.connection.url** instead of **connection.url**

Please see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html

And jdbc: instead of jdbc.